# Why do people learn electronics? Need some practical examples

Tags: practical

Examples of why one would to learn electronics are:

1) He works (or intend to) as an electrical engineer
2) He likes (or needs to) repair electronic equipment

One thing I find it difficult to understand is that some people build circuits just for fun. And there is nothing wrong with that. But are there any **practical** reasons why one would build that circuit? instead of buying one? or at least buy a chip that's going to make the circuit far more easier to build. In woodworking for example, one can build his own table instead of buying it. And it's not only a fun to build, but the table itself is useful and might be more robust and cost less.
So my question is mainly for people who do build circuits. Are there any practical reasons to build these circuits that I'm missing?

Comment: Who's going to design the circuit you buy?

Comment: the electrical engineer

Comment: How is building a table through woodworking for fun any different from building your own light dimmer, or your own audio amplifier, or your own radio? 
And in addition to that, you don't need to have a purpose to enjoy doing something. I enjoy making certain circuits for the experience of learning, even if there is no practical or cost purpose of doing so.
Just like people enjoy sewing their own clothes, which has no monetary incentive in most of the western world, making your own electronics can just be fun for no other reason than it being fun.

Comment: That aside, I feel this is more of an opinion-based question and don't think this is a very good match with the goal of this StackExchange.

Comment: Why do people learn to play a musical instrument? 99.99% of them will make no appreciable return on their investment in time and cash. Some deranged people murder just for fun yet 99% of them will end up in jail. What about pottery classes or religion? Why do people do this? VTC.

Comment: @JorenVaes I already said it's fine for doing it for fun, I'm was just asking for some practical reasons beyond fun. I didn't say that doing it for just fun is not worth it.

Comment: Use the gender-neutral ‘they’ instead of ‘he’ or ‘she’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is not the end goal of the circuit your building it for, but to understand the hows and why's of it all, usually starting blind from the outside you have no understand of why things are done a certain way, or what constraints are in place, maybe what things can be swapped out for others

Think of it like baking, some people cook from scratch to learn all this, while others just buy the completed item, usually for less, some people enjoy the process far more than the end result

In combination to this, the new skills you learn on this project your doing for fun can make things cheaper and easier for later projects you do need resolved as you have a prior knowledge base

Other times are that the item you are after does not exist, or is in an undesirable form / unrealistic price. This is where many of my pet projects end up, e.g. want to log 300 thermocouples to 0.05C and feed that straight into python via a USB link? good bloody luck going commercial, as a hobby project it only cost $250, and I learned enough that if I did it again, it would be cheaper still.

Comment: Thanks' for the example, that's the practical examples I'm asking about.

Comment: my questions was closed by some closed minded people, wow this is dangerous.

Comment: I think you should rework the question, usually they prefer questions with a clear solid path in mind, e.g. What practical reasons are there for an electrical engineer to redesign something that already exists vs buying one? and clean up any fluff to be directed to making a case to be answered.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work with these people, they think I'm trying to shake their foundations. While in reality I'm asking a true question. Anyway thank's for your answer again.

Comment: @BiteBytes I'm sorry that is the way you feel. I understand what you are saying, but keep in mind that the StackExchange here is not meant to be a forum or discussion platform. We are not scared of you 'shaking [our] foundations', but your question is simply not the purpose of this website. The goal is to set up technical 'Issue->solution' format to help people. If discussion is what you want, there are plenty of forums and chatgroups out there who would happily entertain discussion of your question in less formal context.

Comment: @BiteBytes my foundations were definitely shaken badly.

Comment: @Andyaka Forgive me Maxwell, for I have sinned? May Kirchhoff have mercy upon thy soul.